# Просмотр трафика с и дальнейший его анализ с помошью языка python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Мне нужно просматривать исходящий или приходящий url ip и как то с помощью python 3.6 его постоянно анализировать. Возможно это сделать с помощью python?
И Wireshark обертку и понятные api не могу найти.

Comment: вы хотите анализировать [access.log](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access.log)  http-сервера?

Comment: Мне нужно анализировать свой трафик. (если это возможно)

Comment: попробуйте конкретную задачу указать. К примеру, есть pcap файл, узнать сколько запросов к каждому http host было отправлено.